# listening to pouchdb changes since a given date

Tags: pouchdb

I'm trying to replicate to a localDB but I've found that my production docs are huge and users run out of space, I also notice that there is a `since` option but the [documentation](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) is not clear enough, cause sequence number might vary depend of the user.

I can set it to replicate docs from a given date instead of doing an allDocs operation? or what is a best practice to avoid or limit this behavior?

```
localDb.sync({
  live: true,
  retry: true,
  since: ??, 'date in milliseconds maybe?'
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly It is no supported, i ended up using views

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know this myself, but looking at the [PouchDb docs](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) apparently "since" in replicate/sync refers to the sequence number of the database. So if you use the [database "info" api](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#database_information) it returns a sequence number in the "update_seq" attribute.

So the "since" value can be a number or the special value 'now'. From what I have read, I don't think it refers to a date or time. Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah but sequence number does not work for me, I will probably end up using views :(